# Least Squares Derivation

Tags: linear-algebra, regression

I was reading [this](https://files.nyu.edu/mrg217/public/ols_matrix.pdf/) to review the derivation of the ordinary least squares estimator but I'm having trouble differentiating (4). Can someone please help explain why

$ \dfrac{\partial (\hat{\beta}'X'X\hat{\beta})}{\partial \hat{\beta}} = 2X'X\hat{\beta} $

I understand all the other steps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice first that you might guess this formula because if $X$ and $\hat{\beta}$ are $1 \times 1$ then it reduces to the formula for the derivative of $x^2$ from calculus.

Let's derive a multivariable product rule that will help us here.  Suppose
$f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and suppose
$$f(x) = \langle g(x), h(x) \rangle$$ for some functions $g:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and $h:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$.  Then if $\Delta x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is small (and $g$ and $h$ are differentiable at $x$), we have
$$\begin{align*}
f(x + \Delta x) &\approx \langle g(x) + g'(x) \Delta x, h(x) + h'(x) \Delta x \rangle \\
&= \langle g(x),h(x) \rangle + \langle g(x), h'(x) \Delta x \rangle
+ \langle g'(x) \Delta x, h(x) \rangle + \langle g'(x) \Delta x, h'(x) \Delta x \rangle \\
&\approx \langle g(x),h(x) \rangle + \langle g(x), h'(x) \Delta x \rangle
+\langle g'(x) \Delta x, h(x) \rangle \\
&= \langle g(x),h(x) \rangle + \langle h'(x)^T g(x), \Delta x \rangle
+ \langle g'(x)^T h(x), \Delta x \rangle \\
&= f(x) + \langle h'(x)^T g(x) + g'(x)^T h(x), \Delta x \rangle.
\end{align*}$$
Comparing this result with
$$f(x + \Delta x) \approx f(x) + \langle \nabla f(x), \Delta x \rangle$$
we discover that
$$\nabla f(x) = h'(x)^T g(x) + g'(x)^T h(x).$$
This is our product rule.  (I'm using the convention that the gradient is a column vector, which is not completely standard.)

Now let $g(x) = Ax$ for some matrix $A$.  So $g'(x) = A$.
What's the gradient of the function
$$\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \langle g(x),g(x) \rangle \\
&= \langle Ax, Ax \rangle \\
&= x^T A^T A x \quad \text{?}
\end{align*}$$

By our product rule the answer is
$$\begin{align*}
\nabla f(x) &= 2g'(x)^T g(x) \\
&= 2 A^T A x.
\end{align*}$$

This is the result that you wanted to derive.

Answer (score 1):

First we need to note that $X'X$ is a symmetric matrix as $(X'X)'=X'(X')'=X'X$.

Now,Using basic matrix differentiation,we know that for symmetric matrix $A$,$\dfrac{\partial (x'Ax)}{\partial x} = 2Ax = 2x'A$ where $x$ is a vector and dimensions are *proper*.
hence result follows trivially.

Note:Actually we can say more,if $A$ is *any* $n \times n$ matrix, $x$ is $n \times 1$ vector,then,

$ \dfrac{\partial (x'Ax)}{\partial x} = x'(A'+A)$

Proof:$$ x'Ax = \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}x_ix_j$$
Differentiating wrt to $x_k$,we get,
$$\dfrac{\partial (x'Ax)}{\partial x_k}= \sum_{j=1}^n a_{kj}x_j + \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ik}x_i\ ;  \forall k = 1,...,n$$
hence,$$\dfrac{\partial (x'Ax)}{\partial x} = x'A'+x'A$$

Hence result follows.

More details on Matrix differentiation can be found on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus .

Thanks.